# Show the same Article Available in Other Categories

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, post-meta

What i want To Do is to show **Related Articles via Categories**

For example I have a Movie Named " ABC " in Category Named HDTV , and this movie is Also added in other Categories Via the Same Title .

**And Here Is an image that shows the case.**

[image]

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: you need to use category

Comment: what do you mean by that ? cause im already using categories .

Comment: okay can you please place your single.php

Comment: here is it : http://paste2.org/46bHjGOa

Comment: its block I can't open

Comment: ok now on pastebin http://pastebin.com/YEX95SQF . More info : im using SaladMag Theme , that screenshot in my Question is not from my website . its from another one .

Comment: okay but I give you solution.As I understand you want post belongs to which categories

Comment: please check updated code.Now you want to just paste it

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create secondary loop and use it.

```
//     $categories = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
     $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
     foreach ( $categories as $category ) { 
       echo $category->name;
     }
```

**Description**

```
get_the_category( $post->ID );
```

This tag may be used outside The Loop by passing a post id as the parameter.

Note: This function only returns results from the default “category” taxonomy. For custom taxonomies use get_the_terms().

Comment: thanks but i think You didnt understand me , i dnt want to show other posts , i want to show the category name and when u click on any of theme it does take you directly to the article in that category .

Comment: ok wait a second i ll try it

Comment: soory it didnt work for me , 
<?php

                                $categories = get_the_category();
                                $tags = get_the_tags();
                                $post_id = get_the_ID();
                                $categories = get_post_categories( $post_id );
                                ?>

Comment: <?php

                                $categories = get_the_category();
                                $tags = get_the_tags();
                                $post_id = get_the_ID();
                                $categories = get_post_categories( $post_id );
                                ?>

Comment: it shows that error : Array ( [0] => 90 [1] => 15 )

Comment: no it didnt work for me :/

Comment: Nothing works im adding that code on single.php , i think you may need to see how loop looks like : http://pastebin.com/LJRSEN8E

Comment: @Marwisso Please put updated code you will get solution

Comment: it did show only the cats of the curent article 
img : http://imgh.us/index_12.png

Comment: you have to check is there any other category related to this